# How to flatten an array using Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm just starting with Neo4j - and at the outset, I realize that there could be better tools to get these results I'm describing, but I'm using Neo4j in order to learn Cypher. I've written a query that returns numeric country codes that meet three MATCH criteria, returning a list of countries that match all three. Each criterium has a root node and 2-10 relationships to the specific criteria node for the type, such as:

```
CREATE (root:Age {name: "root"}),
       (A1:Age {name: "Younger"}),
       (A2:Age {name: "Older"}),
(root)-[:AGE]->(A1),
(root)-[:AGE]->(A2)
```

(The other two criteria simply have numeric values which range from 1-10.) Each non-root node in the graph has a 'countries' array property which holds the country IDs that apply to the criteria, created such as:

```
MATCH (a:Age {name: 'Younger'})
SET a.countries = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
RETURN a

MATCH (a:Age {name: 'Older'})
SET a.countries = [7,8,9,10,11,12]
RETURN a
```

The query below finds matches for each criteria, and then uses the APOC intersection function to only return the country codes that have matches for all three criteria:

```
MATCH (a:Age) WHERE a.name = 'Older'
MATCH (h:Health) WHERE h.rank > 0
MATCH (w:Wealth) WHERE w.rank < 11
RETURN filter(x IN  collect(apoc.coll.intersection(apoc.coll.intersection(a.countries,h.countries),w.countries))
WHERE x <> [])
```

The query runs fine, returning the proper results. However, I get results like the following multi-level array, and would prefer to get a simple array of country codes. Currently I get this: [[9], [8], [10], [7], [12], [11]], I would like to instead get this: [9, 8, 10, 7, 12, 11]

Note that the

```
filter(x IN ... WHERE x <> [])
```

in the RETURN statement is there to get rid of empty country arrays that otherwise show up.

Finally, I will be adding 3-5 more criterium, so a solution that handle even deeper levels of the result would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should work:

```
MATCH (h:Health) WHERE h.rank > 0
UNWIND h.countries AS hc
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT hc) AS hcs
MATCH (w:Wealth) WHERE w.rank < 11
UNWIND w.countries AS wc
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT wc) AS wcs, hcs
MATCH (a:Age) WHERE a.name = 'Older'
RETURN apoc.coll.intersection(a.countries, apoc.coll.intersection(hcs, wcs)) AS res
```

It collects, in a single flat collection, all distinct matching `Health` countries; and it does the same for matching `Wealth` countries. Then it gets the matching `Age` node and does a 3-way intersection between its countries and the other collections. The resulting collection is flat because all 3 intersected collections are flat.

This query is also more performant than yours because it avoids [Cartesian Products](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/cross-product-cypher-queries-will-not-perform-well/).

Comment: Yes, this provided correct results: [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

Answer (score 0):

You could try collecting the country collections of the nodes, then running REDUCE() using apoc.coll.intersection()

```
MATCH (a:Age) WHERE a.name = 'Older'
WITH COLLECT(a.countries) as allCountries
MATCH (h:Health) WHERE h.rank > 0
WITH allCountries + collect(h.countries) as allCountries
MATCH (w:Wealth) WHERE w.rank < 11
WITH allCountries + collect(w.countries) as allCountries
RETURN REDUCE(intersection = HEAD(allCountries), countries in TAIL(allCountries)
      | apoc.coll.intersection(intersection, countries)) as intersection
```

The advantage with this one, besides avoiding cartesian products on your matches, is that the RETURN can remain exactly the same no matter how many extra `MATCH ... WITH` you plan to add in the query.

EDIT

The above query only works if you also want the intersection to execute on countries within each of the matched node types. For example, the :Wealth match likely matches on multiple :Wealth nodes, each with their own collections of countries. The question is, within each node type in the match, are their countries meant to be unioned or intersected?

The above query assumes they're meant to be intersected, but it seems like you want the union of the countries instead, and then to intersect those countries among different node types. This requires a different kind of query.

```
MATCH (a:Age) WHERE a.name = 'Older'
WITH a.countries as intersection
MATCH (h:Health) WHERE h.rank > 0
WITH apoc.coll.intersection(intersection, 
  REDUCE(union = [], countries in collect(h.countries) | 
         union + countries)) as intersection
MATCH (w:Wealth) WHERE w.rank < 11
WITH apoc.coll.intersection(intersection, 
  REDUCE(union = [], countries in collect(w.countries) | 
         union + countries)) as intersection
RETURN intersection
```

Comment: The first query returned: `Invalid input 's': expected 'n/N' (line 8, column 58 (offset: 400))
"      | apoc.coll.intersection(intersection, countries) as intersection"` (pointing at the 's' in 'as' in the last line of your query
                                                          ^

Comment: The second query returned a result column of "intersection" with a result of []

Comment: Ah, missing close paren at the end of the intersection call in the first query, fixed. As for the second, let me tinker with that a bit. In the meantime, can you confirm if the :Health and :Wealth nodes matched in this query are single nodes, or multiple...and if they're multiple, do you want to union all of their collections first per node type before intersecting with the others, or do you want the intersection among themselves first?

Comment: Syntax issue gone from your first query, but now returns empty list []. :Health and :Wealth nodes can match multiple nodes (10 each for both, ranks ranging 1..10.), so multiple matches of a particular node type can happen. "WHERE h.rank > 0" and "WHERE w.rank < 11" will match all of the :Health and :Wealth nodes - making the only active filter be :Age for that query. My intent is to union all the countries for each node type, and then intersect between the different types (:Age, :Health, and :Wealth). BTW, for each node type, a country will only be assigned to a single country array.

Comment: Think I fixed the second query. You only have one :Age node, so we can just use the countries collection as is for the intersection. I had an unnecessary COLLECT() in there.

Comment: Now getting the following error with your latest query: Invalid input '(': expected an identifier character, whitespace, '?', '!', '.', node labels, '[', "=~", IN, STARTS, ENDS, CONTAINS, IS, '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '=', "<>", "!=", '<', '>', "<=", ">=", AND, XOR, OR, AS, ',', ORDER, SKIP, LIMIT, WHERE, LOAD CSV, START, MATCH, UNWIND, MERGE, CREATE, SET, DELETE, REMOVE, FOREACH, WITH, CALL, RETURN, UNION, ';' or end of input (line 4, column 28 (offset: 131))
"WITH apoc.coll.intersection(intersection, "

Comment: Not sure what to tell you on this one, I can run it without syntax errors, and the open paren of the function call shouldn't be giving neo4j any problems. Can you verify your version of Neo4j and APOC?

Comment: My bad - I switched to a database that did not have APOC, and forgot to switch back. Your latest query returns the correct results: [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

Comment: Finally got there. You have some options now, play around with this one and cybersam's and find the query which works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need APOC for this:

```
MATCH (a:Age) WHERE a.name = 'Older'
WITH [collect(a.countries)] as prev
MATCH (h:Health) WHERE h.rank > 0
WITH prev + [collect(h.countries)] as prev
MATCH (w:Wealth) WHERE w.rank < 11
WITH prev + [collect(w.countries)] as contSets
RETURN FILTER(c in contSets[0] WHERE ALL(contSet in contSets WHERE c in contSet))
```

Comment: This returned an empty array: []

Comment: If I run this but RETURN contSets (instead of the filter), I get the following: [[[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]], [[5], [], [4, 10], [6], [3, 8], [12], [2, 9], [], [1, 7], [11]], [[9], [8], [7, 10], [6], [5, 12], [4], [], [3, 11], [2], [1]]]